# glVertexAttribPointer - invalid operation - buffer present

Tags: c++, ubuntu, opengl

I am having some kind of a weird problem here. I am using OpenGL 4.3 on ubuntu 15.04 with glfw3 and glew. In my code I have the following function call:

```
void VertexElement::bindAttribute(uint32 stride) {
    GL_CALL(glEnableVertexAttribArray(mAttributeIndex));
    GL_CALL(glVertexAttribPointer(mAttributeIndex, mComponentCount, (GLenum) mDataType,
        mIsNormalized ? GL_TRUE : GL_FALSE, stride, reinterpret_cast<void*>(mDataOffset)));
}
```

`GL_CALL` in debug mode basically makes:

- `glGetError()`
- call function
- `glGetError()` -> not ok -> throw exception

I then get an `INVALID_OPERATION` error in `glVertexAttribPointer()`. Using a debugger I could verify that all the parameters are as expected:

`glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, FALSE, 16, 0x0000000000000000)`

I was checking the documentation and realized that there is not a single possibility for `INVALID_OPERATION` documented. All the restrictions on `type` and `size` do not seem to apply here, since in this call `pointer` is `NULL` not even the possible zero-Buffer object applies. But even if it werent, i checked the binding on `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` before the call and there is the buffer 1 bound currently.

So in my opinion none of the possible errors described in the documentation seem possible in my case, or am I missing something? And what could be a possible other reason for this? Could it be something in my setup? Im using ubuntu natively on a laptop and installed the nvidia-346 driver, but I am connected to the machine using teamviewer from my desktop (but the error also happens when there is no teamviewer connection). The following is the output from the `GL_VERSION`, etc calls:

```
Version:    4.3.0 NVIDIA 346.59
Renderer:   GeForce GT 755M/PCIe/SSE2
Vendor:     NVIDIA Corporation
```

I have tried creating a debug context and I wanted to attach a debug message callback but all of the following functions are nullptr: `glDebugMessageCallback`, `glDebugMessageCallbackARB`, `glDebugMessageCallbackAMD`, `glDebugMessageControl`, `glDebugMessageControlARB`, `glDebugMessageControlAMD`

I am a bit baffled by these results and would appreciate any hint to the right direction!

Comment: GL 4.3 NV and no debug callbacks? I can hardly believe that. Also, why do you throw exception on every GL error? That's horrific.

Comment: Do you have a VAO bound at the time of the call?

Comment: @MateuszGrzejek Yea, couldnt beleive it either, but thats what i get. And for the exception throwing, this is a very early stage, need to refine it some more, just needed to know where somethings going wrong.

Comment: @RetoKoradi There is a VBO bound, but no VAO i guess. But the same laptop when i was using windows i didnt bind a VAO either and there never was a complaint.

Comment: @CromonL Well, the nvidia driver in use definitively supports debug callbacks (which are actually a core feature in GL 4.3). There must be some issue with your extenstion loading.

Comment: Ok, to sum up the issue with missing extensions: I forgot the glewExperimental, because I've never been using GLEW on windows before. Now i get all the debug output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you got a Core Profile context on Ubuntu. With the Core Profile, using VAOs (Vertex Array Objects) is required.

The Core Profile spec says:

> An INVALID_OPERATION error is generated by any commands which modify, draw from, or query vertex array state when no vertex array is bound.

This includes `glVertexAttribPointer()`.

Answer (score 0):

Without more context it's difficult to pinpoint any errors, but I can try to give some advice based on steps I normally take to debug these things:

1. Make sure you're not using a CORE profile context, in practice there isn't much reason to do so(if this solves your problem, it could be the VAO not being bound correctly).
2. Break out all the code required to draw a triangle, put it in a single method that goes through all the steps each frame, loading a shader, creating and binding a VAO, VBO and IBO, setting uniforms to sane and hardcoded values. If this doesn't work according to a decent reference implementation, maybe your drivers are broken, if it does work, compare the code flow to your primary implementation and make sure you understand exactly what happens(using a debugger to step through the whole loop for instance).

I realize this might not be a definitive answer, but it could help you get somewhere.

Comment: Yes, I was using a core profile! I kinda have both now, im using a VAO and im not using a core profile and it works, im too scared to remove the VAO again to see if it works then ;). I will accept the answer below because it includes a quote from the spec, but will upvote yours too!

Comment: -1. Using core profile is always recommended. It is the only profile, that needs to be present in GL implementations. That's why certain platforms may not support compatibility profile (like Mac OSX, [where only core is available for GL 3.2 and higher](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Core_And_Compatibility_in_Contexts)). What you say is simply wrong.

Comment: If you're on a platform where using the core profile has a significant impact, such as on OSX as you linked it, I would assume it's pretty clear that it makes practical sense to use it in that situation. If you're on a platform such as Windows, using the core profile does't provide a lot more than limiting your options as it stands currently. Saying something is "simply wrong" because there are exceptions to the statement is, "simply wrong", providing examples of exceptions is useful  however. Nevermind the fact that it actually solves the problem and thus answers the question. :)